# no puedo resolver este problema Python

Tags: python

En la tienda de los hermanos Roque es tradición presentar las latas de conserva apiladas
triangularmente: en el primer piso una lata, en el segundo piso dos latas, en el tercer piso tres, y
así sucesivamente. Por ejemplo, seis latas se ponen así:

[image: latas apiladas]

Los hermanos tienen grandes problemas para realizar los pedidos de latas, ya que no todo
número de latas se puede apilar triangularmente. Por ejemplo, 8 latas no se pueden apilar. Crea
un programa llamado, en el que dado un número natural introducido por el usuario,
comprueba si es adecuado para apilar

```
n = int(input("Introduce la altura del triángulo (entero positivo): "))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print("*", end="")
    print("")
```

solo llego hasta aquí, pero no sé como hacer para que muestre un mensaje cuando un número no es adecuado

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad. En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario mostrar el trabajo realizado para poderte ayudar. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que tienes para poder tomar en cuenta la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya agregue el código

Comment: Pon además un título descriptivo: "no puedo resolver este problema Python" no da  pistas de tu problema. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el `if` para la comprobación. El código está dentro de un bucle para que vuelva a solicitar otro número.

```py
def isTriangular(num):
    if (num < 0):
        return False
    
    sum, n = 0, 1 
    while(sum <= num):
     
        sum = sum + n
        if (sum == num):
            return True
        n += 1 
    return False

while True:
    n = int(input("Introduce la altura del triángulo (entero positivo): "))

    if not isTriangular(n):
        print(f"El número {n} no es un triangular")
        continue
        
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            print("*", end="")
        print("")
    break
```

Comment: No es correcto. Según tu respuesta la condición para que sea triangular es que sea impar? de dónde sale eso? el 6 es triangular (1+2+3) y no es impar. El 5 es impar, pero no es triangular. Ademas no tiene nada qué ver el numero de latas (que es el número que ha de ser triangular), con `n`, que es  la altura del triángulo y que puede ser cualquier nümero.

Comment: @abulafia tienes completamente razón. Muchas gracias por la corrección!

Comment: ahora me arroja el error: the name "num" is not defined

Comment: Es por esta línea `if not isTriangular(m):` ponle `n` en vez de m

Comment: Ya funciona, muchas gracias